# How to load only needed CSS per component (React js)

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I've started to code my first React app and it's awesome, but I can't figure out how to manage css files per-component(so the actual CSS won't load if it is not necessary).

React with webpack(correct me if I'm wrong please) wraps the project in such a way that at every given moment the app loads only what it needs(in terms of JS).

So if I have my main `App` component with only two buttons visible: `btn-01` and `btn-02`, and inside of this component I have another two: `component-01` and `component-02`, and they are hidden till the corresponded button is clicked(`btn-01` for `component-01`), these components won't be loaded until the actual button is clicked(am I getting this right?), however this is not the same with css as I can tell, because I see the css of each of these(`component-01` and `component-02`) components loaded right away the `App` is loaded, even though none of the buttons are clicked.

I'm not a big fan of inline styling, but I did test it with `css module`, but the result is the same in this aspect. So I'm not even sure if this is possible to implement in an easy way.

Here's a code, so perhaps I'm not implementing it correctly, but please don't mind the none-DRY code etc.

So as you may see, the style of `Component-01` and `-02` are loaded even though there is no need for them at the moment(none of the button is pressed).

`App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Component_01 from "./Component-01/Component-01";
import Component_02 from "./Component-02/Component-02";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isComponent_01: false,
    isComponent_02: false,
  };

  toggleComponent01 = () => {
    this.setState({
      isComponent_01: !this.state.isComponent_01,
    });
  };

  toggleComponent02 = () => {
    this.setState({
      isComponent_02: !this.state.isComponent_02,
    });
  };

  render() {
    let showComponent_01 = null;
    if (this.state.isComponent_01) {
      showComponent_01 = <Component_01 />;
    }

    let showComponent_02 = null;
    if (this.state.isComponent_02) {
      showComponent_02 = <Component_02 />;
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button className="btn-01" onClick={this.toggleComponent01}>
          Btn-01
        </button>
        <button className="btn-02" onClick={this.toggleComponent02}>
          Btn-02
        </button>

        {showComponent_01}
        {showComponent_02}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`Component-01.js` (and `Component-02.js`, just with `-02.js`)

```
import React from "react";
import style from "./Component-01.module.css";

function App() {
  return <div className={style["component-01"]}>Component-01</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you can use styled component for react it's limit the style scope for the component here a link https://styled-components.com/

Comment: Thank you @adel, but I don't like the inline styling even with css-in-js, I prefer to use css(sass) for this for variety of reasons.

Comment: Using React.lazy() might help: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html Use it to lazy load components. Not sure if the CSS will be lazy loaded as well, but worth a shot